# Spring Boot: entity doesnt create foreign key entity null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Recently I got an issue I can't seem to figure out. I have entity class called order that has a one to one relationship with two other entity classes called Product and Customer. When I try to set the customer the foreign key is set in the database. However when I try to do the same thing with the product he doesn't do it. The customer is created in the database the moment when the order is made. But the product is retrieved from the database.

My apologies for the written code. This is the controller we use to save the entities to the mysql database

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/makeorder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String MakeOrder(@RequestBody String Json, RedirectAttributes ra) throws IOException {
        List<Orders> o = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] lijst = Json.split("r");
        String[] naamsplit = Json.split("CustomerNaam" + "=");
        String naam = naamsplit[1].substring(0, naamsplit[1].indexOf("&"));
        naam = naam.replace("+", " ");
        String[] adressplit = Json.split("CustomerAdres" + "=");
        Customer customersaved = new Customer();
        String adres = adressplit[1].substring(0, adressplit[1].indexOf("&"));
        adres = adres.replace("+", " ");
        if (naam != "" && adres != "") {
            if (Json.contains("=on")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < lijst.length; i++) {
                    if (lijst[i].contains("=on")) {
                        String[] getidstring=lijst[i].split("boolean");
                        int getidnum=parseInt(getidstring[1].substring(0,getidstring[1].indexOf("=")));
                        Optional<Product> optionalEntity = productRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(getidnum));
                        Product product = optionalEntity.get();
                        Orders order = new Orders();
                        String splitter=getidnum+"=";
                        String[] lijst2 = lijst[i].split(splitter);
                        int nummer = parseInt(lijst2[1].substring(0, 1));
                        order.setNumberOfProducts(nummer);
                        order.setCustomer(customersaved);
                        orderRepository.save(order);
                        var updateOrder = orderRepository.findById(order.getId());
                        Orders orderUpdated = updateOrder.get();
                        orderUpdated.setProduct(product);
                        orderRepository.save(orderUpdated);
                    }
                }

                return adres;
            }
            else
            {
                return "redirect:/";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "redirect:/";
        }



    }
```

These are the entities Product, Customer and Order

Product:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "productid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "productname")
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    @Column(name = "availability")
    private boolean availability;

    @Column(name = "photo")
    private byte[] photo;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "productid"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "categoryid"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Category> category;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "Product")
    private Orders Order;




}
```

Customer:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customerid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname ;


    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname ;


    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Orders> orders;


}
```

Order:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "orderid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "numberofproducts")
    private int numberOfProducts;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="customerid")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Timeslot timeslot;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Product Product;


}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code is nearly impossible to read. You do know Spring can automatically deserialize your string into a Java object, right? You can't, and shouldn't, be working on raw JSON strings like this.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider you are right that the code isn't optimally written. But you can ignore that part. The main issue is about the relationship between our entities. Hibernate doesn't link the product with the order that's why I put the entities also in the question